# Naming convention of events in redux js

Tags: redux

Redux will be dispatching actions for state change. What are naming conventions of action types in redux?

Answer (score 19):

There are a few conventions around the community, I'll list the ones I know of and think are useful here:

1. The most common convention is to **keep the action types ("event types") in `CONSTANT_CASE`**.

   *This avoids spelling errors, where the action has a type of `my_type`, but the reducer expects a type of `my-type` or `My_Type`.*
2. Another very common convention is to **save the action types in a separate file as constants**, e.g. `var MY_ACTION_TYPE = 'MY_ACTION_TYPE';`, and to use them from there.

   *This also avoids spelling errors, so you don't expect an action to have a type of `MY_ACTION_TYP`. If the variable doesn't exist, you'll get an error immediately, especially if you're linting.*
3. A not quite as common, but imho very useful, convention is to **scope the actions to a project and a domain**. This approach was popularized by [Erik Rasmussen](https://twitter.com/erikras) in his ["Ducks" proposal](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux), which specifies that action types have to be in this shape: `var MY_ACTION_TYPE = 'appname/domain/MY_ACTIONTYPE'`.

   *This avoids the case of two action constants having the same value. E.g. imagine you have a admin area and user facing area, and both have forms dispatching a `'CHANGE_USERNAME'` action type. This will make two reducers pick up the same action, where one shouldn't pick the other one up. This can happen on accident, and is very annoying to track down. By prefixing them with the app- and domain name, one avoids this issue: `'appname/admin/CHANGE_USERNAME'` is different from `'appname/user/CHANGE_USERNAME'`!*

That's all the conventions I know of and use, but I'm sure somebody else has more – what have you used and found useful in your projects?

Comment: I would like to note that scoping action types by reducer reinforces the **incorrect** idea that [actions map 1:1 to specific reducers](https://github.com/reduxible/reduxible/issues/8). In reality, a single action can (and often should) be processed by different reducers, and vice versa.

Comment: That is correct, while that doesn't keep one from picking up an action in different reducers it might seem like that. I'll think about how to edit the answer to reflect that, or do you maybe have an idea? EDIT: Updated the answer

Comment: I would just change it from `app/reducername/ACTION_TYPE` to something like `app/modulename/ACTION_TYPE` or `app/domain/ACTION_TYPE` to make it clear reducers and action creators might belong to a single group but actions don’t belong to particular reducers.

Comment: Do you include `appname` just to make it easy to find/recognise all actions?

Answer (score 15):

There are also some conventions around naming asynchronous action types. If you have a set of actions to represent an api call to get a user, you can split them up into something like:

- `FETCH_USER_REQUEST` - for when you first send the api call
- `FETCH_USER_SUCCESS` - for when the api call is done and successfully returned data
- `FETCH_USER_FAIL` - for when the api call failed and responded with an error,
- `FETCH_USER_COMPLETE` - sometimes used at the end of the call regardless of status

Answer (score 0):

There is a new pattern that addresses this, [redux-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto).

It takes the ideas of reducer composition one step further. Where instead of having a file that represents your reducer and creating individual actions functions.

redux-auto's approaches to have folders with individual JS files representing each action/transformation on the state and dynamically exposing this as functions

example

```
└── store/
    ├──user/
    │  └── index.js
    │  └── changeName.js
    └──posts/
       └── index.js
       └── delete.js
```

Now from anyway in your app you can write

```
import actions from 'redux-auto'
...
actions.user.changeName({name:"bob"})
```

store/user/changeName.js

```
export default function (user, payload) {
    return Object.assign({},user,{ name : payload.name });
}
```

Thats is!

If you want to listen for redux actions in third-party reducers. You can use as loose quality check against the function.

```
action.type == actions.user.changeName // "USER/CHANGENAME"
```

For something more advanced you can even see if an action is owned by a specific reducer

```
// Returns true if it's an action specifically for user
if(action.type in actions.user)
```

You can read more on the [project page](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto#overview)

Answer (score 0):

See Redux official styleguide: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters

- [Model Actions as Events, Not Setters](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters)
- [Write Meaningful Action Names](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#write-meaningful-action-names)